# С чего лучше начинать изучение php?

Tags: php, c++

Пару лет программировал на С++, в основном для себя, а потом иногда подворачивались работы по удаленке, но а в целом достаточно сложно что-то находить. Вариант с офисом не подходит, так как в городе ничего такого нету, а ехать в другой не особо есть смысл, так как нужно будет идти на стажера или джуниора, но там берут в основном студентов IT специальноcтей , а у меня другая специальность (по которой я работать не собираюсь).

Так что решил взять php для заработка, а в C++ параллельно развиваться дальше. Как раз пишу проект на С++, которому нужно взаимодействие с пользователем, вот и сделаю через сайт и, возможно, наберусь опыта для удаленки. Можно было бы выбрать, конечно, питон, или шарп, или яву, или что-то ещё для веба, но не особо хочу тратить на это время, так как больше фанат плюсов и нужен быстрый старт для заработка (поддержания себя на плаву, пока что-то с плюсами не найду в будущем). Так вот, с чего начать? Какую литературу посоветуете? Возможно, стоит выбрать ту, в которой описывается переход с С++ на php, чем просто все о php? Некоторые после Си/C++ просто берут php справочник и уже пишут что-то, так как код в принципе понятен, но мне такой подход не нравится, ведь все же языки-то разные, хоть и похожи синтаксисом, так что не хочу писать плохой код или попадать раньше времени на грабли, которых можно было бы избежать, прочитав пару книжек. С html и css дело имел ещё давно, и базового понимания мне должно хватит, так как не планирую дизайнером быть или верстальщиком, а за javascript уже позже возьмусь. Ну и с базами MySQL, SQLite и т.д. тоже имел дело. То есть мне для начала нужна литература для понимания основ, а там уже что дальше по списку, если тоже посоветовать можете на будущее. Также не совсем ясно насчет фреймворков, точней о том, какой выбрать, к примеру, ZendFramework 1 или какой-то другой.

Надеюсь, в целом описал ситуацию, и если вам не сложно, могли бы вы составить примерный список, по которому мне нужно двигаться? Ведь многие из вас сталкивались с этим и у вас, скорей всего, есть своя профессиональная точка зрения на этот счет.

Comment: Насчет того, что берут в основном студентов IT специальностей - большое заблуждение, берут тех, кто в этом разбирается. У нас в группе, например, были отличники, которые толком ничего не понимали. Были и те, кто говорил умные вещи, о которых я и до сих пор не знаю, но при этом, опять же, сами ничего сделать не могли.

Уже почти 3 года в php и думаю сейчас - может на junior`a в плюсы податься? Т.к. "для себя" и реальный опыт - две абсолютно разные вещи.

Если дальше хотите на плюсах - то лучше на другое и не смотреть, пусть даже и временно.

Хотя для общего развития может быть и полезно )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скажу вам честно: самая лучшая литература по php - это официальная документация. 
Пока книга успеет выйти, то большая часть ее успеет устареть.

Попробуйте пройтись по урокам 
http://phpbuilder.ru/learn

Потом изучить взаимодействие с бд. 
Поставьте перед собой задачу и решите ее, если вы зашли вообще в тупик, спросите на форуме и продолжайте работать. С каждым разом увеличивая сложность задания, подглядывайте в документацию для поиска нужной функции. Когда дойдете до такого уровня, что вы можете делать безопасный и правильный код, на процедурки переходите на ООП. И практика, практика.

Comment: А Котерова стоит прочитать или документации хватит? А если есть друг, который только начинает программировать, то ему тоже с документации или все же Котерова?

Comment: @yot, Котеров на самом деле тоже устарел. Лучше все-таки с документации, у PHP она очень хорошая. После изучение основ можете начать поглядывать сюда - http://getjump.github.io/ru-php-the-right-way/

Comment: @andreyqin, Документация на русском сойдет? http://php.net/manual/ru/ Она полная? И что насчет фреймворка?

Comment: @yot, более чем, могут быть не переведены некоторые новые функции, появившиеся в версии 5.5, но это мелочи. Из фреймворков - Laravel, Symfony или Yii.

Comment: @yot, да, это официальная документация.